# Authlogic/Rspec/Rails 3.2: UserSession.find returns nil in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, authlogic

Relevant models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    acts_as_authentic
end

class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper :all
    protect_from_forgery
    helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

    private

    def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
    end
end
```

Here is the Rspec:

```
describe "Rate Function" do
    include Authlogic::TestCase
    before(:each) do
        current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, persistence_token: "pt", email: "new@example.com", password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
        activate_authlogic
        UserSession.create(current_user)
    end
    it "Some test for rating..." do
        get "/reviews/rate", {:format => :json, :vehicle_id => 3}
        # other stuff here, doesn't matter what it is because it never gets here
    end
    after(:each) do
    end
end
```

This is the Rspec definition of User:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "email@example.com"
        password "password"
        password_confirmation "password"
        persistence_token "pertoken"
    end
end
```

The problem is that every time I invoke `current_user` from any controller method, it always returns `nil` and that's because `UserSession.find` always returns `nil` in the `ApplicationController`.

Funnily enough, if I run the following in the Rspec (not in a controller), the `UserSession.find` works properly and `just_created_session` is not nil.

```
UserSession.create(current_user)
just_created_session = UserSession.find
```

So the problem is specific to `UserSession.find` being called in a controller.

Any help is appreciated.

Environment

```
Ruby: 1.9.3p392
Rails: 3.2.12
Authlogic: 3.2.0
Factory Girl: 4.2.0
Rspec: 2.13.0
OS: Windows 7
```

Update:  I looked at `UserSession.create`, and all it does is this:

```
def create(*args, &block)
    session = new(*args)
    session.save(&block)
    session
end
```

Since I don't even store the return value when calling from the spec, nor does the method seem to be doing any storing, I'm not sure how we expect `User.find` to find anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried just getting rid of it but it didn't help.  The method does get called as I have a breakpoint there.  Looking deeper, authlogic's persistence.rb file has a method called persisting? which ends up returning nil which is the issue.

Comment: Did you figure out what's going on here? I am running into this issue and it's been delaying me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem with UserSession.find returning nil in the controller when driven from RSpec request specs.

Running the database cleaner in between RSpec tests caused authlogic's UserSession.find to (sometimes) return nil, even though the session was valid. I would UserSession.create(model) and immediately, UserSession.find would return nil. But only from the request specs. This was frustrating.

However, it was not authlogic's fault. I discovered a memoization in the model class which was surviving the database cleaning. This maintained a phantom reference to an active record object, and this reference, accidently passed to UserSession.create, caused the symptom. The session was created, and immediately, unfindable, but only when the database cleaner ran.